# Youtube Video upload

Tags: python, video, upload, youtube

I'm trying to make a video upload to youtube using the [gdata api](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/).
I also had a look at the [hello-youtube](http://code.google.com/p/hello-youtube/) example.
Does anyone knows if I can use youtube browser upload without requiring the user to loggin to youtube? I want the user to select a video from their computer, and upload it to my developer account (not the users account). Is this possible?
In case it its, can someone help me with an example?

Many thanks!

EDIT

I found that it's possible to log from server side using any normal youtube account (not sharing my password, although my account still subjected of being suspended in case someone submits bad content). The code can be found on the "ClientLogin authentication for installed applications" of the [python developers guide](http://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very bad idea because you are responsible for the content of your channel and the usage of your account.

It also means you will share your Google password with the entire world. Bad idea, bad idea, bad idea, ...

Comment: So I should use the Direct Upload option? Do you hava an example code for this?

Comment: I don't know any website that would allow to upload videos (and view them) permanently without logging in. If you really want that, you have to take care of the storage and player yourself. (Oh and forget typical HTTP upload. Most hosting providers don't allow to upload more that an few MB. Maybe Amazon S3 or similar is the solution.

Comment: I found that it's possible to log from server side using any normal youtube account (not sharing my password, although my account still subjected of being suspended in case someone submits bad content). The code can be found on the "ClientLogin authentication for installed applications" of this page https://developers.google.com/youtube/1.0/developers_guide_python

Comment: Do you realize you have to put your password in cleartext in a Python file with this technique?

Comment: Can you explain to me what's the problem with this? I'm not very experienced with web development.

Comment: This is old, but I think may be relevant. The problem is that there's a chance someone having access to your server, which would make your account vulnerable. However, most of the time there is no problem doing that. A better pratice would be to put this password on a environment variable.